# ormlite not working with sqlite JDBC in swing application

Tags: java, swing, sqlite, ormlite

Hi i am using ormlite for sqlite in a java swing form i am getting following error while connecting the database

> [ERROR] SqliteDatabaseType WARNING: you seem to not be using the
>   Xerial SQLite driver.  See ORMLite docs on SQLite:
>   http://ormlite.com/docs/sqlite

without ormlite its working.

here is sample code

```
ConnectionSource connectionSource = null; 
        try {

            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

            connectionSource = new JdbcConnectionSource("jdbc:sqlite:src/database/sms_production.db");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: What you are getting is a _WARNING_ not an error.  ORMLite is trying to tell you that you are using the unrecommended sqlite driver.  Any comment on that?

Comment: i have used the required sqlite driver here is the link of it https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc, may be its support different version of the driver i have downloaded latest